# How can I run a function immediately after the CSS is set?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

**Target:** I need to decide the bottom position of an element once the page loads.
**What I tried:** `componentDidMount()` life cycle method, which turned out to run after only the HTML markup is set, so the position value was wrong because the layout wasn't implemented yet.

Comment: Show some code/sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with JS `window.onload`.

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets images - [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)